# put on google map some point with different color

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I want put the three point in **google map** with **lat long** but i want each point have different color.
This is my code, At the moment this code set one color to all point

```
    function initMap() {

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 11,
            center: {lat: 39.585938, lng: 47.909219}
        });

        heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
            data: getPoints(),
            map: map
        });

        var gradient = [
            'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0)',
            'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
        ]
        heatmap.set('gradient', gradient);
    }

    function getPoints() {
        return [
            new google.maps.LatLng(39.585938, 47.909219,20),
            new google.maps.LatLng(39.585938, 47.909220,20),
            new google.maps.LatLng(39.585938, 47.909221,20),
            new google.maps.LatLng(39.585938, 47.909222,20),
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Your code is currently using a heatmap.  Do you want markers?

Answer (score 0):

You can define custom markers using the `strokeColor` property:

Example :

```
strokeColor: "red",
```

Reference : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    id: "some-id",
    icon: {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
        strokeColor: "red",
        scale: 3
    },
    map: map,
    title: "Any-title",
    position: myLatlng
});
```

References :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols